# I want two rows horizontally using display grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

as my title says i want two rows side by side using display grid problem is i can't select two rows side by side when i use..

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
grid-template-columns: auto;
grid-column-gap:100px;}
```

it creates two rows but vertically and one column. and when i use..

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
grid-column-gap:100px;}
```

it creates two column side by side and two vertical rows like this..

[image]

which is good so far until i click my accordian button when i clicked this happened..

[image]

Both Columns taking height when i clicked which i don't want. the only way is to tackle this problem is create two separate rows side by side. or anybody can give different suggestions would be appreciated i am too exhausted right now to think the logic behind this problem. thanks :)

Comment: not possible with grid yet. `masonry` value for grid is only supported by Firefox in experimental-mode. Easiest way to solve it is with the `column-count`-property: `.grid-container { column-count: 2; column-gap: 100px; }`

Comment: @tacoshy i already tried this but didn't get the desire result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you wish to use `display: grid` properties but I have **not found a way** to do so using those properties. I offer you an **alternative** here, using `display:flex`.

I used Bootstrap's accordion for the example below.

**1)** You need to use some `display:flex` on a container to get its direct children elements (here, blocks/divs) next to one another.

**2)** you need to define 2 child blocks of that container in order to have 2 columns. You can use the `col-6` of bootstrap that does a `width:50%` in order to do so.

**3)** inside those 2 columns, place your accordions. They should act and open without stretching their neighboors that live in the other column.

---

This is what it **visually** looks like:

[image: objective]

---

If you wish to do so, here's a **code example** using **Bootstrap 5.1.3** :

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne-1">
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseOne-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo-1">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo-1">
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseTwo-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree-1">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-1">
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseThree-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordion-2">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne-2">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne-2">
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseOne-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo-2">
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseTwo-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-2">
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseThree-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

          <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

### -- UPDATE --

I have found another way of doing what you have described, still using `display:flex` but with more structural changes in order to respect your description regarding responsive design:

- **on mobile / tablet** : horizontal design with two elements next to each other.? Accordions don't affect the other side's height when opened.
- **on desktop / large screens** : vertical design

Here's a code sample, let me know if it helps (please try responsive to see structural changes).

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                  <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne-1">
                    Accordion Item #1
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseOne-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo-1">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo-1">
                    Accordion Item #2
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseTwo-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree-1">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-1">
                    Accordion Item #3
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseThree-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree-1" data-bs-parent="#accordion-1">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-lg-12">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion-2">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne-2">
                  <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne-2">
                    Accordion Item #1
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseOne-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo-2">
                    Accordion Item #2
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseTwo-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree-2">
                    Accordion Item #3
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseThree-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree-2" data-bs-parent="#accordion-2">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      

          <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i appreciate your effort but i rejected this idea before this is not for me. the picture i've shown above is for tablet and mobile view not for big screen for big screen i want my sidebar vertically in one row and one column and for mobile view i want them (separated side by side in two rows and two columns ) which i've shown

Comment: now only way is left is hard code which i don't to but  i have to design another sidebar for tablet and mobile view and put that sidebar to display none.

Comment: I have updated my answer, still using flex but with the description you gave me to respect your structural changes. Does it help @SheikhFarzaib ?

Comment: that's it. this is what i want. i really appreciate your effort man you've done the great job thanks :)